# Java Thread: According to sun there are only four stages in thread life cycle

Tags: java, multithreading

According to sun microsystems thread has only four stages:

```
  1. New
  2. Runnable
  3. Non-Runnable (Blocked)
  4. Terminated
```

According to them there is no running state.

Why is it so?

What is the state when thread running?

Comment: I can speculate by saying that a thread may or may not be running at any given moment, depending on the scheduler.  So, it makes less sense to say that a given thread be running so much as it makes sense to say whether or not it _can_, or cannot, be run.

Comment: Then according to sun, what is the state when thread has started running?

Comment: @VikasSatpute In a single processor system, how would you observe the state of a thread that is curretly being executed? :) The distinction between "ready to run, but not started", "currently running", "started, but waiting for processor time" is a bit pointless, as it can change many times before the observer can process the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Java docs these are the states defined

1. NEW : when an object of thread (lets call it T) is created.
2. Runnable : when T is started and it participates in consuming the CPU cycles. It is the running state.
3. BLOCKED : when T is blocked on a monitor of a lock (T may be blocked to enter a synchronized block or method as some other thread is executing that block or method )
4. WAITING : Thread is waiting (will not be picked by thread scheduler to consume CPU cycle). Until it is notified or interrupted it remains in this state.
5. TIMED_WAITING : Similar to WAITING state but for a defined time period. Once time period is over it gets out of this state
6. TERMINATED : the thread execution is over (end of run method).

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html

According to the documentation (you read it, didn't you? :)) RUNNABLE means "A thread executing in the Java virtual machine is in this state."

So it seems to be just the choice of words in the enumeration that is confusing you.

Answer (score 2):

Better see the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html#RUNNABLE):

> public static final Thread.State RUNNABLE
>
> Thread state for a runnable
> thread. A thread in the runnable state is **executing** in the Java
> virtual machine but it **may be waiting** for other resources from the
> operating system such as processor.